# NestJS: The injected dependencies are undefined when getting service from the app context

Tags: nestjs

I've followed the instructions of the official app:
https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications
Here is my code:

patient.service.ts

```js
...
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Patient) private patientRepository: Repository<Patient>,
    @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request,
  ) {}
...
  findOne(id: string) {
    return this.patientRepository.findOneByOrFail({ id });
  }
...
```

main.ts

```js
...
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

const patientService = app.select(PatientModule).get(PatientService, { strict: true });
const doctor = await patientService.findOne({
  id: addedPerson.id,
});
```

But this error shows up in the console:
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOneByOrFail')`

In summary, it seems the dependencies are not injected into the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've injected `REQUEST` the `PatientService` is actually `REQUEST` scoped so you must `await app.resolve()` rather than `app.select`. [Here are the docs on getting a scoped provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref#resolving-scoped-providers)